# How do you configure GRUB to boot EFI files?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, mbr

Typically I use a GPT disk and would use systemd-boot to manage things, but I'm working with an older computer, so I have to use GRUB2.

I'm using a USB stick to run two OS: Pop OS and Ventoy. What I want to do is make it so I can boot off of GRUB that is preinstalled with Pop OS to load the EFI files that Ventoy uses. How can I achieve this? This is formatted as MBR so that it would work with my older PC. I have grub-customizer installed and working

Comment: Is Ventoy an OS? As far as I know, it is a FOSS to make multiboot USB.

Comment: UEFI recommends use of gpt partitioning. Ubuntu can boot from MBR partitioned drive or gpt with either UEFI or BIOS. But really best to always use gpt partitioning. If gpt, you need an ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. There are two versions of grub2. For BIOS, it uses grub-pc and for UEFI it is grub-efi-amd64 (for 64 bit systems). You can only boot from grub other installs that are in same boot mode, or all UEFI or all BIOS. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi